# Possible methods to deal with artifacts when drawing billboards to a cubemap

Tags: texture, particles

When drawing billboards to a cubemap, the billboard texture was incorrectly aligned on the boundaries of the cubemap between different sides.

My guess is that the false projection of the billboard texture shape using the perspective cameras when drawing the cubemap caused this.

My question is that without using a geometry with dimensions (such as using a plane geometry for the billboard texture to attach) to achieve the correct projection, is there any other methods to reduce the artifacts? e.g. process on the pointCoord?

[image: cubemap problem]

[a screen record showing the matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-cMGQFCOYs&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: More about the context: I need to use the billboards in **points** mode. So a billboard is attached in screen space from a single vertex position.

Comment: Screenshots of the problem would have made this much easier to answer by more people FYI!

Answer (score 3):

Change the projection to always be the same no matter which face is being rendered.

The simplest way is you use the direction from billboard to the camera instead of the direction the camera is facing to rotate the billboard.